# Where to start for Augmented Reality in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, string

I have done lots of applications for iOS using Xcode. And i want to explore the feasability of Augmented Reality in iPhone. I searched for it and found that we need  SDKs for it i.e Qualcom or String. Can anybody suggest me whichone is best to start with? And any sample tutorial for start-up related to that.?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn about Augmented Realty and many different APIs, IDEs, Engines and SDKs, this book may be the best resource for you

[Pro iOS 5 Augmented Reality](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430239123)

It is for iOS 5, but I see no adoption that prevents it from working with iOS 6. It is great! It shows Qualcomm demoes, Open-CV, String and more!'

The author works with you throughout the book with examples and explanations which are beyond interesting and cool.

After reading this book I feel like a professional, just read the reviews, a great valuable book!

Answering your ultimate question, which is the best SDK/API? I think that it depends on what you want, they have different purposes, functionalities, learning curves etc. I suggest you read this book to explore all

Comment: Thanks Dev! Could you tell me one more thing, which SDKs/tools i need to download to satrt with ,like you said both have different purposes? In my requirement, i need to detect markers and do different events on the basis of markers.

Comment: String is good, Qualcomm also, Arkit and Mixare are decent too, this book covers it too

Comment: @VarunMehta if this helped please up vote and tick

Answer (score 1):

You could use [iPhone-AR-Toolkit](https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit). It's up on GitHub, and I've added in lots of helpful things like a radar, modern callouts etc...

[image]